# When is the 4th item in the Custom Number Formats used for a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

The help online [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/264372/how-to-control-and-understand-settings-in-the-format-cells-dialog-box), states:

> ## Custom Number Formats
>
> ...
>
> Before you create your own custom number format, you need to be aware of a few simple rules governing the syntax for number formats:
>
> - Each format that you create can have up to three sections for numbers and a fourth section for text.
>
>   > ```
>   > <POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
>   > ```

I can see references to the first 3 sections, but I don't see any reference to the forth one.  What is it for?  How does it affect formatting?

Comment: it is for what it says it is for, text.  Since you can color the text or not show it there is the forth to deal with text like `xxxx`.  When text is entered in the cell it falls into that category.  For example `General;-General;General;` will make any numbers entered in the cell general format and any text will show as blank.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah, for non-numeric entries.  I understand.  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is for what it says it is for, text.

Since you can color the text or not show it there is the forth to deal with text like `xxxx`.  When text is entered in the cell it falls into that category.

For example

```
General;-General;General;
```

Will make any numbers entered in the cell general format and any text will show as blank.

And:

```
[Green]General;[Red]-General;[Black]General;[Blue]General
```

Will make positive numbers Green, Negative numbers Red, Zeros Black and any Text Blue.